# Objective C Play Video

Tags: objective-c

Here is my Implementation file:

```
-(IBAction)playvideo {

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"Intro" ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];

playercontroller = nil;


}
```

And here is the strange error:

```
2012-08-03 01:48:40.085 Assaultive[5569:16a03] An instance 0x9b5ad50 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x8549f10> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x9b5cde0: Observer: 0x9b58690, Key path: nonForcedSubtitleDisplayEnabled, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x9b5ce60>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x9b5cfa0: Observer: 0x9b54b90, Key path: presentationSize, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x9957780>
)
```

It loads the player view and direclty closes the subplayerview.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error. Somewhere in your code (or apple's), there is a KVO Observer not being removed. I don't think you can just set `playercontroller` to nil and expect it to retain itself. Try holding on to a reference to it and become it's delegate.